# can't SSH from one machine to other

Tags: ssh

I have 2 laptops: Laptop 1 with only ubuntu 20 with no VMs whatsoever. Laptop 2 windows and VM (ubuntu 20).

So the scenario is that from the VM ubuntu (Laptop 2) I can SSH the 1st but not the other way. I checked the 1st one has port 22 enabled for ssh just like the 2nd one.

Could someone please help a new linux enthusiast please!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make the virtual network adapter on the VM a "bridged" adapter so the VM is seen as another machine on the network, rather than sitting behind NAT (network address translation).

Power down the VM, go to the VM settings, click on the network adapter, and select "bridged".

Comment: Thanks Gordster!! :D

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to AskUbuntu :)

TL;DR: Forward the SSH port on the VM provider (a.k.a. VirtualBox or VMWare Player) if you're behind a NAT or connect the VM with a bridged adapter.

The fact that you can SSH into the "real" Ubuntu machine from the VM may have to do with how the networking of your VM provider is set up. Odds are you are either using VirtualBox or VMWare Player. I don't have much experience with the latter so I can't really guide you through the steps there but I can try and provide some help if you are using VirtualBox.

In the networking world we usually employ NATs (Network Address Translators) to let networks such as LANs (the ones at home) use private addresses and still be able to connect to the public internet. These NATs are the reason why we have a different IP address in our machine in a home network than the one we see when going to sites such as [What's my IP?](https://www.whatsmyip.org). If you would rather use a command line to check your public IP you can run `dig myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` to check that provided you have `dig` installed. You can then see how the IP address for your interface, which you can check if you run `ip a` is most likely different.

NATs are pretty handy *but* they do pose some problems when connecting to a host behind a NAT. We have to *open the ports* as they usually say so that we can forward outer requests to inner machines. When you add a VM it will usually sit behind a NAT handled by the VM provider. Unless you open ports to allow outside connections you won't be able to SSH into the VM... Not, the reason why it works the other way around is because establishing connections from *within* the NAT is transparent to the hosts behind it. The NAT will just "write down" that a host (in this case your VM) opened a connection to wherever and seamlessly forward the replies to the host (your VM once more).

Cutting to the chase, you can either forward the ports on the VM, which you can do as shown in [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-port-forwarding-in-virtualbox/) article on TechRepublic which does a better job of explaining things than me or you can opt to use a different topology.

If instead of placing the VM behind a NAT you use the `Bridged Adapter` configuration on VirtualBox or the equivalent on VMWare Player you'll see that the VM is assigned an IP just as if it were a totally independent computer on your home/local network. You can check that with `ip a` on the VM. That way, you can now SSH into that new IP that's been assigned to the VM and you won't have to deal with the NAT at all. This configuration makes your VM a full-fledged member of your LAN, which might pose some issues you'd rather not look into. In that case, I would recommend sticking to port forwarding. You can configure this by going to the configuration section of the VM, navigating to the Network tab and selecting `Bridged Adapter` on the `Attached To` menu. Remember to attach it to the interface that's on the same network as your other machine. That is, your WiFi NIC )Network Interface Card) if you're on a wireless network or your Ethernet NIC if you're on a wired one.

At the end of the day you can do what suits you best. I hope this helped a bit and please, if you have any further questions don't hesitate to follow up: I would be happy to help.

Welcome again!

Comment: Thanks Collado!! :D